# Why is my Retrofit Enqueue Failing?

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to use Retrofit library so I can make calls from my Android app to my Django REST API I have created. I have the following code written:

*UserAPI.java*

```
public interface UserAPI {

    String BASE_URL = "http://www.example.com";


    @GET("/json.json")
    Call<JsonObject> getUsers();


    class Factory {

        private static UserAPI service;

        public static UserAPI getInstance(){

            if(service == null){

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .build();

                service = retrofit.create(UserAPI.class);
                return service;
            }

            else{
                return service;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

*JsonObject.java* (this was generated from JSON to Pojo)

```
public class JsonObject {

    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    private String username;
    @SerializedName("password")
    @Expose
    private String password;
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The username
     */
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param username
     *     The username
     */
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The password
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param password
     *     The password
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     The email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param email
     *     The email
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Now, this is where my code actually fails:
*MainActivity.java*

```
UserAPI.Factory.getInstance().getUsers().enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {

                        Log.wtf("Response", "" + response.body());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.wtf("FAIL", "This failed...");

                    }
                });
```

I cannot for the life of my think of why this is happening.

For reference, this is what the JSON file looks at when navigated to on a web browser:

```
[{"username":"testuser","password":"pbkdf2_sha256$24000$9YMUYsV7WuIa$FnokGg8jFlAq3LHGBXgqVHNUnLCQa7pj5ehhWKvNkuU=","email":""}]
```

I apologize for the huge block of text, but I didn't know how else to explain my issue. Any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you able to get the same JSON response if you visit the link from your device?

Comment: Yes I am. I can go to example.com/json.json in the browser and get the correct result

Comment: Does your JSON response always return inside an array? I would expect it to be an object, as does JsonObject.

Comment: What do you mean by this? If it is expected to be an object, how would I change the code to reflect that?

Comment: Generally, json is returned as a map. So it could look something like: {"users": [{"username":"testuser","password":"pbkdf2_sha256$24000$9YMUYsV7WuIa$FnokGg8jFlAq3LHGBXgqVHNUnLCQa7pj5ehhWKvNkuU=","email":""}]}. Then you would add an outer class for Retrofit to parse which simply contains a List<JsonObject> for "users" which represents the array.

Comment: Hmm I see. which lines of code would I change to reflect this?

Comment: I would just plug my suggested JSON into http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and use the classes it generates for you. Then have your Call<> methods use the outer class name. You would need to change the server-side response first to match this, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your `JsonObject.java` class to something else .

**EDIT**

change your interface

```
 @GET("/json.json")
 Call<JsonObject> getUsers();
```

To

```
 @GET("/json.json")
 Call<JSONArray> getUsers();
```

check , if it work , if works , then convert you that JSONArray to  JsonObject

inside the `onResponse` method of your api call

```
  Log.wtf("Response", "" + response.body().getJSONObject(0));
```

Comment: Tried that, refactored it to GeneratedJSON.java and still getting the same error

Comment: ok , rather than Log.wtf("FAIL", "This failed...");  , replace with  

 Log.d("FAIL",""+t.getMessage());   , lets check what error you have got

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: hmm , I am editing , my answer . Your api call is retruning a json array , but  in your interface you are telling that it is returning a jsonobject

Comment: What change could I make to "Call<GeneratedJSON> getUsers();" to make it return a JSON array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116622/discussion-between-shuvro-and-ethanzh).

Answer (score 0):

Because you are receiving an array of users (even though it looks like it is only returning one element), you should change your interface accordingly:

```
@GET("/json.json")
Call<List<JsonObject>> getUsers();
```

And so your `enqueue()` code:

```
UserAPI.Factory.getInstance().getUsers().enqueue(new Callback<List<JsonObject>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<JsonObject>> call, Response<List<JsonObject>> response) {
                    for (JsonObject user : response.body()) {
                        Log.wtf("Response", "" + user.getUsername());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<JsonObject>> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.wtf("FAIL", "This failed...");
                }
            });
```

I would rename the POJO `JsonObject` to `User` or something meaningful as well.